# Movabletype: Make the Recommended Contents function

Tags: php

I didn't have much experiences about the CMS (like wordpess, joomla or movabletype) so I don't know my task is possible or NOT.

My customer, they buy and use the CMS (MovableTypes) to make their website. So now they want me to find or write (Code) the new function for website. That function will be get and show the related blogs (entries) like for example:

"if you go to ebay and click to view a cellphone, the website will give you recommend cellphone which have same properties of the current."

In PHP, I can know how to do this, but in MovableTypes I don't know, have anyone had some experience about the MovableType.

Comment: Can you describe what is it that you want?

Comment: I have said...I use MovableType to make website. Now, I want to have the function that will get the related content for current content which you have click to view. But I don't have any experience about the MovableTypes so I make the question to ask someone about this.

Comment: Have you done any research on your own?

Comment: I had...instead I go to the HP of MovableType and find out the plugin for this situations 1 by 1. But the results are 0. Maybe my experiences are not enough so I don't know how to ask about this. So I have to go here to ask for some one who have exp about this. (I hope so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have documentation for extension development here:
https://movabletype.org/documentation/developer/

Whilst following their framework is usually sensible and worth taking the time to do, most CMSs will also usually allow you to find a place to just write in raw PHP via a very basic extension.

Just make sure you never edit core files.

Comment: Thank for this documents. I will research about this.